# Excel: Get Cell Adress of source Cell when content determined by if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

i have a cell (lets call it A1) which uses an if statement to determine its content.
i.E:

```
=IF(SheetName!H9="";SheetName!H$3;IF(SheetName!I9="";SheetName!I$3;IF(SheetName!J9="";SheetName!J$3;IF(SheetName!K9="<>";SheetName!K$3;"stopped"))))
```

so depending on which statement turns out to be true, the cell A1 will be populated with different content.

so far so good.

now i need to find out the actual adress of the cell that A1 is pulling its contents from.

What function would i use to return the adress of the cell whos content is being displayed in A1?

i did my homework, looked, used the search function on here and many hours have been spent on not finding the answer i need. i found tons of other useful insights into excel, but this problem remains unsolved.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is display the address you want to refer to in a cell (let say `B1`) with almost the same formula as the one you already built:

```
=IF(SheetName!H9="";"SheetName!H$3";IF(SheetName!I9="";"SheetName!I$3";IF(SheetName!J9="";"SheetName!J$3";IF(SheetName!K9="<>";"SheetName!K$3";"stopped"))))
```

This will return a *string* with the address of the cell.

Then, you can get the *value* of the cell with `INDIRECT`. For instance, you can put in `A1`:

```
=IF(B1="stopped","stopped",INDIRECT(B1))
```

I let you change the `B1` with the needed `$` depending on the reference you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions like MATCH, which finds the position (row number from reference) of the desired content. Then you can transform it to show the address.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native formula to get the address of the cell containing the formula.

I found the solution, which should probably function in the formulas in conditional formatting as well.

To get the address of q cell containing the formula you should type:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```